# How to solve private String readText() issue?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This code creates problem to me. Problem is: `dummyTextID`

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(dummyTextID);
```

I've defined `dummyTextID` under **@override protected void**, But had to put reading method under separate `private String` which creates probelm

I'm giving my code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.word);

    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null) {
        finish();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        TextView word = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word);
        word.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        TextView definition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.definition);
        definition.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        TextView details = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.details);
        details.setText(readText());

        int wIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD);
        int dIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION);
        int Index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DETAILS);
        int dummyTextID = getResources().
        getIdentifier(cursor.getString(Index), "raw", getPackageName());


        word.setText(cursor.getString(wIndex));
        definition.setText(cursor.getString(dIndex));
        definition.setText(Html.fromHtml(cursor.getString(dIndex)));
        details.setText(cursor.getString(Index));
        details.setText(Html.fromHtml(cursor.getString(Index)));
    }
}


private String readText() {
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(dummyTextID);


    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new 

    ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int i;
    try {
        i = inputStream.read();
        while (i != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
            i= inputStream.read();
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    onSearchRequested();
}
```

Comment: What does the dummyTextID do ? does it return you a file name .

Comment: @The Dark Knight: Yes!

Comment: See my ans below and make the changes accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to use `openRawResource` to copy a binary across from your raw resource folder to the device.

See the API eg below :

```
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_db_file);
```

But what you are doing is :

```
int dummyTextID = getResources().getIdentifier(cursor.getString(Index), "raw", getPackageName());
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(dummyTextID);
```

Your dummy text id is not binary, Its an int . Convert it to binary and then pass it. This should work .